# How to Run sincNet Speaker Recognition code in jupyter Notebook/Pycharm

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm

https://github.com/mravanelli/SincNet

This is the GitHub link provided above to sincnet.
I wanted to know how I can run this code in jupyter Notebook or in Pycharm.

This is my first time and I have tried a lot before and I am not able to do it.

Can anyone provide me the full instructions to run this code it is very important.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this steps:

**Step 1:**
First download all the files. You just download the whole repository that you have linked (click the green button <kbd>Code</kbd> -> and then click <kbd>Download zip</kbd>). Unzip the files and you'll get a folder, let's call it `project_folder`. Place this folder wherever you like. Let's say that now the code is at path: `/path/to/project_folder`.

**Step 2:**
Now they list the following prerequisites for running the code:

```
Linux
Python 3.6/2.7
pytorch 1.0
pysoundfile ( conda install -c conda-forge pysoundfile)
We also suggest using the anaconda environment.
```

If you have [anaconda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) they suggest the creation of a conda environment. If you do have it you can do in a terminal: `conda create --name myenv python=3.6` and you activate it: `coda activate myenv`.

If you have a different environment you can should create it with python 3.6 because things might not work otherwise. Then you can install the two other dependencies:

1. `pysoundfile` with `conda install -c conda-forge pysoundfile`. If you don't have conda, a simple `pip install PySoundFile` should work too.
2. `pytorch`: you should check this [page](https://pytorch.org) for the exact instruction that you should type in your terminal. It depends on your operating system.

---

Now you can do everything inside a notebook or in a PyCharm project. Let's see first how to do it in a **notebook**:

**Step 3:** Open your notebook from the environment you have created, so that all your packages are available, and cd to the directory where your files are stored. In a cell `%cd /path/to/project_folder`.

**Step 4:** Execute a script inside the folder, let's call it `myScript.py`. You simply write the following in a cell: `!python myScript.py`.

---

To execute in **PyCharm**:

**Step 3:** Create a new project inside the folder where you stored the files.

**Step 4:** Change the interpreter, clicking on something like `<Interpreter>` on the bottom right corner of the window. Select your created environment. You could have also skipped step 2 and created the environment directly into PyCharm, it's the same. Just make sure you have all the packages listed.

**Step 5:** Open the script you want to execute and hit Run.